# filenotfoundexception while uploading in xpage

Tags: xpages

I am using Domino Server 9. And the server is running proper.

At some stage it reaches a state where an upload to an XPage
upload control fails with a FileNotFound error (it can't find a
temp file created for the file being uploaded, more details
about this later).

In some cases the server reaches this state may be once or twice in a day.

Once this state occurs any file being uploaded will produce the
same FileNotFound error.
The only way to stop this happening is to restart the server.

Complete exception details:

```
CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx:
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:WINDOWSTEMPnotes618068xspuploadupload_00010082.tmp (The
system
cannot find the path specified.)
at
com.ibm.xsp.context.FacesContextExImpl.(FacesContextExImpl
.java:26
7)
at
com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext.(DominoFaces
Context.
java:32)
at
com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContextFactoryImpl.getFace
sContext
(DominoFacesContextFactoryImpl.java:67)
at
com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.getFacesContext(Faces
Controll
erImpl.java:175)
at
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.getFacesContext(FacesServlet.jav
a:352)
at
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:141)
at
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:13
7)
at
com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesSer
vlet.jav
a:103)
at
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeSe
rvlet(Co
mponentModule.java:576)
at
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(N
SFCompon
entModule.java:1267)
at
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterI
nvoker.i
nvokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
at
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletI
nvoker.d
oService(ComponentModule.java:796)
at
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doServic
e(ComponentModule.java:565)
at
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFCo
mponentModule.java:1251)   at
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)   at
com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService
(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
at
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(L
CDEnvironment.java:297)   at
com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx:java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:WINDOWSTEMPnotes618068xspuploadupload_00010082.tmp (The system
cannot find the path specified.)   at
 com.ibm.xsp.http.FileUploadRequestWrapper.doParseRequest(FileUploadRequestWrapper.
 java:153)
 at
com.ibm.xsp.http.FileUploadRequestWrapper.getParameter(FileUploadRequest
Wrapper.java:573)

at
javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:161)
at
com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(ExternalContextImpl.java:6
29)
at
com.ibm.xsp.context.FacesContextExImpl.(FacesContextExImpl
.java:17
5)
... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:WINDOWSTEMPnotes618068xspuploadupload_00010082.tmp (The    system
cannot find the path specified.)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:190)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:142)
at
com.ibm.xsp.http.fileupload.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReached(De
ferredFileOutputStream.java:183)
at
com.ibm.xsp.http.fileupload.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThresh
old(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:275)   at
```

Answer (score 1):

if this happens, can you access the c:/windows/temp on OS level? 
Is there any special about this directory? Disks space problems perhaps?

Also check the access rights on that folder, maybe something happens so that Domino doesn't have the right to access the temp directory anymore.

Comment: Hi julian, ya we have checked disks space and rights. Everything is fine. If you check this link may be you would get some  more idea. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO68693

Answer (score 1):

I tried a fix to solve the issue. i have changed the temp file storing directory of my domino server to a different directory in my notes.ini file. It solves the problem.